# Customising PDFTRON Signature tool in Webviewer

Tags: signature, pdftron

I have been exploring pdftron for my website on my trial version,but I could not find any specific examples for customising the signature tool,Any help appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

This guide provides information about the signature tool and some of the APIs available https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/guides/advanced/signature

For example here's a code snippet from the guide about how to customize the sign here element.

```
var createSignHereElement = Annotations.SignatureWidgetAnnotation.prototype.createSignHereElement;

Annotations.SignatureWidgetAnnotation.prototype.createSignHereElement = function() {
  // signHereElement is the default one with dark blue background
  var signHereElement = createSignHereElement.apply(this, arguments);

  signHereElement.style.background = 'red';
  return signHereElement;
}
```

If you want to do more complicated customizations to the UI, the WebViewer UI components are all open source and able to be modified. Here is a link to the SignatureModal component that can get you started https://github.com/PDFTron/webviewer-ui/tree/master/src/components/SignatureModal

This guide discusses how to edit and run the UI https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/guides/ui/advanced-customization